# How to explain the following Beautiful Soup code?

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-3.6

i am new to Beautiful Soup and trying to learn it, while i am learning it , i got stuck at a certain code.Below is the code:

```
for link in bsObj.findAll("a"):
    if 'href' in link.attrs:
        print(link.attrs['href'])
```

I am unable to understand the meaning of ".attrs" how to use it and what does it do?
Secondly, when i execute this code it prints all the links but omits href as a variable from it.? what is going on? can someone please explain it to me?

Below is the complete code :

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Bacon")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
for link in bsObj.findAll("a"):
    if 'href' in link.attrs:
        print(link.attrs['href'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of beautifulsoup4, "attrs" refers all attributes with value of a html tag. For "a" tag, it may have "href" attribute, "class attribute" etc. attrs return a dictionary, so you'll get the value by accessing the key "href". For example: when it prints the following link:

"/wiki/Wikipedia:Protection_policy#semi"

then, dictionary["href"] = "/wiki/Wikipedia:Protection_policy#semi"
so the value for the key "href" is "/wiki/Wikipedia:Protection_policy#semi"

Just write the following code:
print(link.attrs) then everything about this will clear to you.